# Is there any faster ways to count intersections between lines and polygons for large datasets with python?

Tags: python, intersection, shapely

I utilized the Polygon.inetersects() method to judge intersections between line dataset and polygon dataset with "shapely", but it turn out to be slow but I have a large number of data. Can anybody give any suggestions?